# How to Remove the Borders between the cells and rows of a Html Table?

Tags: c#, html

I am Creating an PDF using the HtmlTable in Code behind.I had set a border for a Table by using the line

```
HtmlTable table1 = new HtmlTable();
table1.Attributes.Add("border", "1");
```

This creating the Borders between the cells and the rows also. What can i do If i need the borders only on top and bottom?

I have tried the below code.but i didn't work.

```
table1.Attributes.Add("border-top", "solid");
table1.Attributes.Add("border-bottom", "solid");
```

Please help me anyone.

How to set only the top and bottom borders of a HtmlTable?

Answer (score 1):

The `border` attribute on a `table` elements indeed sets borders around all cells as well. So instead of it, set `border-top` and `border-bottom` as you have tried, but since they are CSS properties and not HTML attributes, they cannot be set directly on an element. Instead, they can be set with an HTML `style` attribute:

```
table1.Attributes.Add("style", "border-top: solid; border-bottom: solid");
```

However, this creates borders with the browser-dependent width of `medium` (typically two pixels). If you want one-pixel borders, set

```
table1.Attributes.Add("style", "border-top: solid 1px; border-bottom: solid 1px");
```

Answer (score 0):

U can solve this by CSS.

Demo: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezhil/run4s/144/)

```
    table{
width:400px; 
margin:0 auto; 
background:#4679BD;
border-top:1px solid red;
 border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```